# Runnables not being executed by Handler in android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have an `IntentService` class in my android app which sends UDP packets to a server. In my earlier implementation I had not used handlers and the code was working fine. I wanted to implement queueing of the packets before being sent. So I created two runnables for writing to and reading from the queue respectively. And tried to execute them using handlers. But the runnables do not get executed and a NullPointerExecption is thrown. I think there is something wrong with my implementation of handlers. I would like to know the correct way of executing runnables using handlers. Thanks in advance. I have posted some code snippet and logcat below:

```
wHandler = new Handler();
rHandler = new Handler();
writer = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
            switch (pType) {
            case 0:
                while (send) {
                    queueMessageForSending(msg.getBytes());
                }
            case 1:
                // Float f = new Float(delayField.getString());
                // for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
                while (send) {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(delay);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if(send)
                        queueMessageForSending(msg.getBytes());
                }
                // break;
            case 2:
                // for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
                while (send) {
                    int u = want(30);
                    // int e=(int)Math.floor(-1*log(u)/(log((float)2.718)*2));
                    // System.out.println(e);
                    String data1 = "";
                    while ((u--) > 0)
                        data1 = data1 + msg;
                    if(send)
                        queueMessageForSending(data1.getBytes());
                }
                // break;
            case 3:
                //float f2 = Float.parseFloat(delayField.getText().toString());
                // for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
                while (send) {
                    int u = want(30);
                    // int e=(int)Math.floor(-1*log(u)/(log((float)2.718)*2));
                    System.out.println(u);
                    String data1 = "";
                    while ((u--) > 0)
                        data1 = data1 + msg;
                    System.out.println("data length :" + data1.length());
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(delay);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if(send)
                        queueMessageForSending(data1.getBytes());
                }

            }
            wHandler.post(this);
        }
    };
    reader = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            while(send){
                if (!writeQueue.isEmpty())
                {
                    byte[] sendData = (byte[]) writeQueue.elementAt(0);
                    sendPacket(sendData);
                }
            }
            rHandler.post(this);
        }
    };

wHandler.post(writer);
rHandler.post(reader);

void sendPacket(byte[] data) {
    //if(socket!=null){
    try {
        System.out.println("\nClient:: Sending packet: " + " to " + addr
                + port);
        if(seq==100000)
        {
         seq=0;
        }
        Date d = new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +
        c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" +
        c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    //System.out.println(time);
        long sentTime = c.getTime().getTime();
        //System.out.println(sentTime+"  "+seq);
        header=" "+seq+" "+sendData.length+"  "+sentTime+"  "+time+"  ";
        seq++;

        String s1= new String(sendData);
        String s2= header+s1;
       // System.out.println(s2);
        byte[] sendDataFinal = (byte[]) s2.getBytes();
        spacket = new DatagramPacket(sendDataFinal, sendDataFinal.length, addr, port);
        socket.send(spacket);
        writeQueue.remove(data);
        String resultTxt="Sent Packet at:"+DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy h:mmaa", System.currentTimeMillis());
        broadcastIntent1.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, resultTxt);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

void queueMessageForSending(byte[] data)
{
    if (data.length > DEFAULT_DATAGRAM_SIZE)
    {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "Message too long: limit is " +
    DEFAULT_DATAGRAM_SIZE + " bytes");
    }
    synchronized(writeQueue)
    {
    writeQueue.addElement(data);
    writeQueue.notify();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[UdpService]
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at com.example.udpmessageclient.UdpSendService$1.run(UdpSendService.java:119)
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 09:46:59.022: E/AndroidRuntime(915):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Can't tell for sure because you didn't post all your code, but my bet is that the problem is a producer/consumer problem with writeQueue-  that the last element was removed between the isEmpty call and the get call.  You really ought to be using some kind of locking to prevent that from being a problem.  A counting semaphore would be perfect here, it would also allow you to not busy wait if no data is available.

Comment: @Gabe I have now posted the code for the functions `sendPacket()` and 'queueMessageForSending()` which are called within the runnables.

Comment: Which line is UdpSendService.java:119

Comment: its `wHandler.post(this);`

Comment: Okay... I moved the queue writer thread to an `AsyncTask`. And the queue is read from the main thread of the `IntentService`. But since `AsyncTask` is only for short background tasks, whereas my thread runs for a long time(till stopped by user), I'm not sure whether this is a good approach. Although the code executes now

Answer (score 0):

Start these `runnables` in a `Thread` like this :

```
Thread t =new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // do whatever you want to do inside runnable

            // after functionality inside runnable is complete...call handler
            Message msg= new Message();
            msg.what=1;
            h.sendMessage(msg);
        }
});
```

after that you can do required functionality inside `handler`

```
 Handler h =new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
        {
            // do whatever you want to do in handler            
        } 
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.should I call the `start()` method on the threads? And where should the `runnables` be declared?

Comment: yes...start() method should be called on threads. Besides you can declare the runnables inside thread constructor. check to see my updated answer.

Comment: the method you are suggesting is to pass Messages to the handler. But I want to pass Runnables to the handler. Could you please tell me the code for this. I do not want to execute threads separately since android is not thread safe. If you can suggest any other way of doing this apart from handlers that will also do. Thanks again

Comment: I would like to suggest you to use ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() with executorService.submit(Runnable) method for executing your 2 Runnable in a sequence.

Comment: for reference: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: @Mehul I want to execute the two runnables concurrently.

Comment: Ok.let me ask one doubt.R those runnables depend on each other?

Comment: @Mehul yes they are. one of them writes to a queue.and the other reads from the queue